# How does unavailability of a gyroscope affect gaming?

Tags: android, hardware

I am aware that most games use accelerometer data for phone orientation (eg, temple run). But most AR/VR/MR games require gyroscope. How does it help in the games? What are the methods that can be used to compensate the absence of a gyroscope in a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gyroscope is a device that is used to maintain a reference direction or provide stability. It's used to sense angular rotational velocity and acceleration. It is required in a smartphone, for example, to be able to record and watch 360-degree videos or photo.

In a game, for example, it provides a GUI that enables a user to select menus by tilting. Image stabilization is one of the applications, and it prevents the trembling from affecting the quality of the image. It enables smooth rotations and is capable of providing precision motion.

And regarding the methods that can be used to compensate the absence of a gyroscope, according to [TechAhead](https://www.techaheadcorp.com/knowledge-center/how-gyroscope-sensor-work-in-smartphone/):

> Most applications in a smartphone today, work best when there is a Gyroscope sensor in the phone. For instance, the recently popular Pokemon Go game showed how Augmented Reality adds to the experience of gaming, however, what’s interesting is, AR won’t be possible without a Gyro sensor. If your phone doesn’t have a good Gyro Sensor, the same can be enabled using GyroEmu Xposed module in any Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

A gyroscope in a phone means in some apps (Like VR) it moves on the screen when you move the phone. This only works for apps that have it coded to enable gyroscope to work. So In temple run it won't affect anything.